# How can i create constructor with autowired and non autowired fields simultaniosly?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a system which makes some action. This system creates for each object a separate thread using:

```java
stp.scheduleWithFixedDelay((EditSite) ctx.getBean("EditSite", site), threadTimeParams);
```

I want to create a constructor with "Site" parameter, but I should keep somehow  my autowired constructor working.

```java
public class EditSite{
    private final A a;
    private final B b;
    private final C c;

    private Site site;

    public EditSite(@Autowired A a, @Autowired  B b,@Autowired C c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public void run(){ check(); }
    public void check(){}
}
```

My IDE said that I can't create `public EditSite(Site site, @Autowired A a, @Autowired  B b,@Autowired C c)`. I used to have a field annotations before, but recently I saw an article that said that field annotations are bad and decided to refactor my code. How can I do it?

Comment: I do not advise mixing injections (which are fields but do not represent an objects "state") with an objects "state" (represented by your "site" value). I would rather create a new class having all four values as "normal" constructor parameters being created by yourself and not via dependency injection, i.e. a normal Java "EditSiteProcessor" initialized with a, b, c and a site which then gets passed to your scheduler.

Comment: It seems that `Site` object serves as a call argument rather than as a dependency so it should not be injected at all. Better way is to pass `Site` object into `run()` method.

Comment: @NikolayShevchenko yes, you are right. But how can i pass it to run method while having a code like in question? (check the scheduleWith ... line)

Answer (score 2):

You need to create your bean explicitly in the configuration.
You don't need any autowiring inside your class:

```
public class EditSite{
  private final A a;
  private final B b;
  private final C c;

  private Site site;

  public EditSite(Site site, A a, B b , C c) {
      this.site=site;
      this.a = a;
      this.b = b;
      this.c = c;
  }

  public void run(){ check(); }
  public void check(){}
}
```

And config for that:

```
@Configuration
public class EditSiteConfig {

  @Bean
  public EditSite editSite(A a, B b, C c){
    Site site = getSite(); //since site is not a bean, you need to get it manually
    return new EditSite(site, a, b, c);
  }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use field autowiring, for example:

```
@Autowired
private final A a;

@Autowired
private final B b;

@Autowired
private final C c;

private Site site;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already used them, but i heard that field autowiring are [link](https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/field-dependency-injection-considered-harmful/)bad.
Are you sure it's a good idea?

Comment: @just4ask4, I'm use in production :)

Comment: Field autowiring is a bad practice because Spring will inject your dependencies through reflection. Such code might be hard to test and that is why constructor injection or setter injection is a better approach - you are not coupled to Spring to get your object with dependencies running.